# Django form is not saving into the db

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm developing a django project where I need to collect data for a student pass application the view.py is as follows

```
def BusPassForm(request):
school = admindb.SchoolDetail.objects.all()
place = Place.objects.all()
subtime = SubTime.objects.all()
if request.method == 'POST':
    name = request.POST.get("name")
    age = request.POST.get("age")
    dob = request.POST.get("dob")
    mobile = request.POST.get("mobile")
    adhaar_no = request.POST.get("adhaar_no")
    address = request.POST.get("address")
    school_name = request.POST.get("school_name")
    start_place = request.POST.get("start_place")
    end_place = request.POST.get("end_place")
    time_periode = request.POST.get("time_periode")
    profileimage = request.POST.get("profileimage")
    idimage = request.POST.get("idimage")
    adhaar_image = request.POST.get("adhaar_image")
    try:
        buspassform = PassForm(name=name, age=age, dob=dob, mobile=mobile, adhaar_no=adhaar_no, address=address, school_name=school_name, start_place=start_place, end_place=end_place, time_periode=time_periode, profileimage=profileimage, idimage=idimage, adhaar_image=adhaar_image)
        buspassform.save()
        messages.success(request, 'application submitted')
        return redirect('dash')
    except:
        messages.error(request, 'Error in submitting your appliction')
        return redirect('buspassform')
    print(form.error)

    
return render(request, 'buspassform.html', {'school':school, 'place':place, 'subtime':subtime})
```

the models.py for the same as follows

```
class PassForm(models.Model):

name= models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
time_periode = models.ForeignKey(SubTime, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default=True)
school_name = models.ForeignKey(admindb.SchoolDetail, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default=True)
start_place = models.ForeignKey(Place, null=True, blank=True, on_delete =models.CASCADE, related_name="pass_start")
end_place = models.ForeignKey(Place, null=True, blank = True, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'pass_end')
age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=True)
dob = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
address = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
adhaar_no = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
mobile = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default=None)
idimage = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/ksrtcimage/idimage', null=True, default=None)
adhaar_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/ksrtcimage/adhaar', null=True, default=None)
profileimage = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/ksrtcimage/profileimage', null=True, default=None)
```

the urls.py as

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.homePage, name='home'),
path('login/', views.loginPage, name='login'),
path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name='logout'),
path('register/', views.registerPage, name='register'),
path('dashboard/', views.dashPage, name='dash'),
path('notfound/', views.notfoundPage, name='notfound'),
path('profile/', views.UserProfilePage, name='profile'),
path('test/', views.TestPage, name='test'),
path('buspassform/', views.BusPassForm, name='buspassform'),
path('trainpassform/', views.TrainPassForm, name='trainpassform')

]
```

I used the html files as a multi stage form and read the data using the names of the input field and passed it I also tried using the django default form functions but it also didn't work please somebody give me some instructions immediately this is my college project so any suggestions are helping I'll try it out

Comment: It's not clear what specific problem you are facing with your code or what you are trying to achieve with your Django project. Django has a built-in form system that makes it easy to validate and process user input. You can create a form class in forms.py and use it in your views. This can help you avoid errors and improve the security of your application.

Comment: Yes I tried that also. But the form is not saving into the backend. After submitting the form the data is not saving to the backend I didn't find any error in the code there might be some logical error if you're familiar please give some suggestion if you have

Answer (score 1):

I forget to add the MEDIA_URL into settings that's why the data is not adding into the db. Also I didn't added the request.FILES while collecting the image data from the form. For other users I'm noting this

```
def TrainPassForm(request):
form = IrctcPassFormField()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = IrctcPassFormField(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
return render(request, 'trainpassform.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: also don't forget to add the enctype to the template like
<form id="msform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">